# React Native Version 0.13.1 TabBar Icons Not Showing

Tags: ios, icons, react-native, tabbar

It seems as though the native tabBar Icons aren't showing and packages aren't integrating with the application as well. I am not sure what the problem is and here is my code:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Featured = require('./App/Components/Featured');
var Search = require('./App/Components/Search');

var {
    AppRegistry,
    TabBarIOS,
    Component
   } = React;

class BookSearch extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedTab: 'featured'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
                <TabBarIOS.Item
                    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'featured'}
                    icon={{uri:'featured'}}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedTab: 'featured'
                        });
                    }}>
                    <Featured/>
                </TabBarIOS.Item>
                <TabBarIOS.Item
                    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'search'}
                    icon={{uri:'search'}}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedTab: 'search'
                        });
                    }}>
                    <Search/>
                </TabBarIOS.Item>
            </TabBarIOS>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('BookSearch', () => BookSearch);
```

**But here is the simulator:**

[image]

The simulator properly changes tabs, but the tab icons don't show at all. Would love any help if possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue. Did you add the RCTImage subspec to your podfile?

see: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html#install-react-native-using-cocoapods

```
# Depending on how your project is organized, your node_modules directory may be
# somewhere else; tell CocoaPods where you've installed react-native from npm
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'Core',
  'RCTImage',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTWebSocket',
  # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
]
```